# How to display char array?

Tags: c++

I have a problem with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
char* email(char* nam, char* ln,char* dep,char* comp)
{
  char str[260];
  strcpy (str,nam);
  strcat (str,ln);
  strcat (str,"@");
  strcat (str,dep);
  strcat (str,".");
  strcat (str,comp);
  strcat (str,".com");
  return str;
}
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    char nam[50], ln[80], comp[100], dep[30];
char* e_mail = 0;
cout << "Name: ";
cin >> nam;
cout << "Last name: ";
cin >> ln;
cout << "company: ";
cin >> comp;
cout << "Which department: ";
cin >> dep;
e_mail = email(nam,ln,dep,comp);
cout << "email: " << e_mail << "\n has length: " << strlen(e_mail) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

All of these lines above should make an email adress, meanwhile it prints this:
[image]
I tried to do this with cout at the end of email function but it spoils the end result and doesn't print it correctly.

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::string` in C++?

Comment: You're returning a pointer to a local variable. `str` only exists within the function and is destroyed when the function returns. Therefore the pointer to `str` which the function is returned becomes invalid.

Comment: This is homework for university classes and I was given everything but the function i wrote myself

Comment: It is possible to dynamically allocate memory in the called function and return a pointer to it but that's a bad idea because the caller now has to remember to free the memory.

Comment: The only part I wrote is: char* email(char* nam, char* ln,char* dep,char* comp)   down to   int main() and I really can't change the rest of the code otherwise they won't pass this.

Comment: string email(string nam, string ln,string dep,string comp){
  return nam + ln + '@' + dep + '.' + comp + ".com";
} and string e_mail;

Comment: Then I think you're expected to dynamically allocate the array and return a pointer to it. It still shows your teacher is not very competent because returning a pointer to dynamically allocated memory in a function like this isn't a good idea as I said. Since `main` doesn't free the memory, it will be leaked.

Comment: @QuentinUK The `main` function which was given to the OP expects a char pointer.

Answer (score 2):

```
char *str[260];
```

Is an array of 260 pointers to char, surely you want a 260 chars array:

```
char str[260];
```

Furthermore you are returning a local variable that will go out of scope as the function returns leaving a dangling pointer `e_mail` in main.

An option would be to pass `e_mail` as an argument of the function:

```
void email(char *nam, char *ln, char *dep, char *comp, char *str) //str will point to e_mail
{
    strcpy(str, nam);
    strcat(str, ln);
    strcat(str, "@");
    strcat(str, dep);
    strcat(str, ".");
    strcat(str, comp);
    strcat(str, ".com");
}

int main()
{
    char e_mail[260];
    //...
    email(nam, ln, dep, comp, e_mail);
    cout << "email: " << e_mail << "\n has length: " << strlen(e_mail) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, being C++, you can use [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) instead of C style char arrays.

```
std::string email(const char *nam, const char *ln, const char *dep, const char *comp)
{
    std::string str;
    str.append(nam).append(ln).append("@").append(dep)
       .append(".").append(comp).append(".com");
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    std::string e_mail;
    //...
    e_mail = email(nam, ln, dep, comp);
    cout << "email: " << e_mail << " has length: " << e_mail.size() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not the only problem. `main` will have a dangling pointer even if you make that change.

Comment: I forgot to delete * when I was trying to solve it myself to be honest

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are returning a pointer to an object that does not live when the function returns.

You can solve the problem using various methods. The simplest one is to return a `std::string` from the function.

```
std::string email(char* nam, char* ln,char* dep,char* comp)
{
  char str[260];

  ...

  return std::string(str); // Just to be explicit.
}
```

and change `main` to:

```
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    char nam[50], ln[80], comp[100], dep[30];

    ...

   std::string e_mail = email(nam,ln,dep,comp);
   cout << "email: " << e_mail << "\n has length: " << e_mail.size() << "\n";
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out with (https://stackoverflow.com/users/9254539/bessiethecow) help
Now it should be just like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
char* email(char* nam, char* ln,char* dep,char* comp)
{
  char*str =new char [260];
  strcpy (str,nam);
  strcat (str,ln);
  strcat (str,"@");
  strcat (str,dep);
  strcat (str,".");
  strcat (str,comp);
  strcat (str,".com");
  return str;
}
int main()
{
    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;
    char nam[50], ln[80], comp[100], dep[30];
char* e_mail = 0;
cout << "Name: ";
cin >> nam;
cout << "Last name: ";
cin >> ln;
cout << "company: ";
cin >> comp;
cout << "Which department: ";
cin >> dep;
e_mail = email(nam,ln,dep,comp);
cout << "email: " << e_mail << "\n has length: " << strlen(e_mail) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is certainly a valid solution, my advice, as you are using C++, try to take advantage of it, using C-style code with C++ is like using a Ferrari to go grocery shoping.